# Got 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory` in code using JasperReports API

Tags: java, jasper-reports, noclassdeffounderror

I am working on a simple standalone desktop application which would generate report based on the values passed to the program. There is no database usage. I have designed my JasperReports report  with the iReport designer and added a parameter `ID_NO` and a text field with expression `$P{ID_NO}`

I can preview the report successfully and see what I expected. But I cant generate the report from Java application and pass the parameter `ID_NO`from there. Here is my code:

```
public class MyReportViewer extends JFrame {

    public MyReportViewer(String fileName) {
        this(fileName,null);
    }

    public MyReportViewer(String fileName,HashMap<String, Object> parameter) {
        super("View Report");
        try {
            JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(fileName, parameter);
            JRViewer viewer = new JRViewer(print);

            Container c = getContentPane();
            c.add(viewer);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        setBounds(10, 10, 600,500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        HashMap<String, Object> param = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        param.put("ID_NO", "101-15-980");
        MyReportViewer viewer = new MyReportViewer("test.jasper", param);
        viewer.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The code gives a exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.<clinit>(JRLoader.java:61)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:267)
    at jspertest.MyReportViewer.<init>(MyReportViewer.java:37)
    at jspertest.MyReportViewer.main(MyReportViewer.java:60)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
```

And does not run.

Please give me a clue. I have never used JasperReports or any kind of report generator before.

**Edit:**

Added all the library files from jasperreports4.x.x/lib/.. to the project. Now the exception is gone. Now the console says-

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.ExtensionsEnvironment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

and a small popup says there are no pages in the document. A small windows appears with no report in it.

Comment: And what happens when you run this code? Does it compile? Does it throw an exception? If so, what's the stack trace? Do you see something in the frame? What?

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete question. The last few lines are missing, edited you should see in a while

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your exception is not related with the Parameter issue, which apparently looks good.

It looks like you are missing Apache Commons Logging in your classpath. It runs in preview mode because your IDE does have the correct classpath.

Comment: Download jar from http://commons.apache.org/logging/ and add to your classpath. You may be missing some more libraries

Comment: http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/requirements.html contains a table with the required libraries.

Comment: I have added all the jar files from the jasperreports-4.1.2\lib now the exception is gone and a window popup appears - "The document has no pages" , i can also see the message in the console - "log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.ExtensionsEnvironment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly."

Comment: "The document has no pages" means there are no records in the datasource, thus no report is generated. You should really look into a jasper reports/ireport tutorial. From all you've said, I understand you are trying to generate a report from data that doesn't come from a database. You should look to create a java bean, bind it in your report, and finally generate your report with a `JRBeanCollectionDataSource`.

Comment: Thank you i managed to create my first report. But i am not familiar with ejb beans. So i had to create a dump database.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah that's right. `"The document has no pages"` means there are no records in the datasource, thus no report is generated.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the property in which the report will still display the blank pages even when the data is not present in the report.

**When NO Data property** will allow you to choose different values and different way of showing the report in case the dataset returns zero rows or the report has not data to print.