# How to get .jasper file from .jrxml

Tags: java, build, jasper-reports

In eclipse while i run below build script to be able **get .jasper file** from .jrxml i get following error:

```
build.xml:16: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
```

Build.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <project name="jasperreports" default="compile" basedir=".">
  <path id="classpath">
        <pathelement location="."/>
        <fileset dir="lib" erroronmissingdir="false">
            <include name="**/*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
  </path>
  <target name="compile">
            <taskdef name="jrc" classname="net.sf.jasperreports.ant.JRAntCompileTask"> 
                <classpath refid="classpath"/>
            </taskdef>
            <jrc 
                destdir="reports"
                tempdir="reports"
                keepjava="false">
                <src>
                    <fileset dir="reports">
                        <include name="**/*.jrxml"/>
                    </fileset>
                </src>
                <classpath refid="classpath"/>
            </jrc>
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing parameter to jasper report from java without DB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888064/passing-parameter-to-jasper-report-from-java-without-db)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means you have to add [apache-commons-logging.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadapachecommonsloggingjar.htm) in build path of your project...

Answer (score 0):

i've added below jars to lib folder and classpath it's done: commons-flow.jar barbecue-1.5-beta1 barcode4j-2.0 commons-beanutils-1.8.0 commons-collections-2.1 commons-javaflow.jar commons-javaflow-20060411 jline-0.9.94 js-1.7R1 junit-3.8.2 persistence-api-1.0 saaj-api-1.3 spring-beans-2.5 spring-core-2.5 xml-apis-1.3.04