# NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory

Tags: java, jasper-reports, noclassdeffounderror

I'm new in *JasperReports* and I want to integrate a *JasperReports* into my Java program,
so when I click print button the program will show the report. But I get a *NoClassDefFoundError* when I click the button.

### Code

```
JButton btnReport= new JButton("Report");
btnReport.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) { 
        try{
            String fileName= "src/learnReport/Leaf_Grey.jasper";
            Connection con = connect.getConnect();
            File file = new File(NameFile);
            JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(file);
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, null,con);
            JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint,false);
        } catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }   
});
```

### Runtime error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.<clinit>(JRLoader.java:81)
    at learnReport.Learning$6.actionPerformed(Learning.java:195)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory`  Make sure Apache commons logging lib is also on the runtime classpath of the app.

Comment: See also [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556)

Comment: I already add all the required library
commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
comons-digester-2.1.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
groovy-all-2.0.1.jar
jdt-compiler-3.1.1.jar
joda-time-2.4.jar
now i just get this error  
`net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Byte data not found at : leaf_banner_gray.png
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""`

Thanks for your help guys

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing parameter to jasper report from java without DB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888064/passing-parameter-to-jasper-report-from-java-without-db)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have missed the jar file "org-apache-commons-logging.jar". Load this jar into your project. The Issue going to be resolved.

Comment: thanks
btw i need to load another jar too.
this is all the jar that I load,
`commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar` `commons-collections-3.2.1.jar` `comons-digester-2.1.jar` `commons-logging-1.1.1.jar` `groovy-all-2.0.1.jar` `jdt-compiler-3.1.1.jar` `joda-time-2.4.jar`

Answer (score 0):

Error Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory

Solution

missed the jar file "org-apache-commons-logging.jar".

Download https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/download_logging.cgi

and then add library

Load this jar into your project. The Issue going to be resolved.